# How can I match all of the URLs that have extensions in Nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to have two different `location` directives, one for **all** URLs that have extensions, and one for the rest of them.

I tried this:

```
    location ~* ^/[^\.]*\.[^/]+$ {
        root /$Organization/Storage;
    }
```

But it does not work properly. It works for extension-less URLs too.

What should I write to divide extension-less and extension-full URLs into two distinct `location` directives?

Comment: Show all your locations.